# Difference between 設計 and 提案

Tags: word-choice

Could you please explain the difference in meaning between 設計｛せっけい｝ and 提案｛ていあん｝? Could they be interchangeable to mean "to suggest"?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: They are as different as chalk and cheese...did you look up 設計 in a dictionary?

Comment: Od course, but when I want to say "to suggest smth", both 設計 and 提案 merge in my mind... so I hope for a constructional and decisive comment-help )

Comment: Why, or where, do you want to use 設計 in place of "to suggest"?

Answer (score 2):

提案 is *to suggest* in the sense of *to make a proposal*. You always need another person (for example your business client) to do 提案. In another word, 提案 refers to saying "Let's do ～". Note that 提案 never means *to suggest* in the sense of *to imply/say/remind* (as in "The lion suggests bravery" or "The letter suggests he's angry").

設計 is *to design* (a product, a building, software, etc.) or *to engineer*. As long as you have a good engineering skill, you can finish 設計 all by yourself with a pen and paper, or CAD software. I don't know when this means *to suggest*. 設計 always refers to engineering design which does not require a sense of beauty. Graphic design, interior design, dress design and such are usually called デザイン.